# Codeigniter file upload from a form without ajax/jquery/javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, form-submit, zend-form-element

**Context** : I am updating user_profile data after user registration using form #updateprofileform ,
i am able to process all other form fields using standard validations and insert/update using user_model.
issue is with `resume` field which should accept a file as input type and upload to server and store its path on server (say http://domain/uploads/$filename) to a column in database.

**Expectation** A logged in user , able to view his details(if already in database),update details if incomplete profile.

**Question** : I found methods how we can upload a file to server using CI framework or how we can upload a file in this context using jquery/ajax/java-script. But i am looking for simple solution for above problem which can do the job with out dependency on technologies.

user_profile.php (view)

```
<table>
<form class="row" name="updateprofile" action = "<?php echo base_url()?>user/user_profile" method="POST">
<tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email ID</label></td><td><input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email-ID" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($email)) echo $email;?>" /> <span style="color:red"><?php  echo form_error('email'); ?></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td><label for="resume">Resume</label></td>
        <td>
          <input name="resume" placeholder="Upload resume" type="file" value="<?php if (isset($resume)) echo $resume;?>" />
          <span style="color:red"><?php  echo form_error('resume'); ?>
          </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase" name="updateprofile" value="updateprofile" formaction = "<?php echo base_url()?>user/user_profile">Update Profile</button> </div></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

user_controller

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
$config = array(
        'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
        'allowed_types' => "doc|docx|pdf",
        'overwrite' => TRUE,
        'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
        //'max_height' => "768",
        //'max_width' => "1024"
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    }
  public function user_profile()
    {  
      $resume = $this->input->post('resume');
  if ($this->user_model->set_user_profile($id,FALSE) )
            { if($this->do_upload($resume)){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_success','Updation Successful!');
                  echo validation_errors();}
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_error','Error! Please try again later.');
                redirect('user/user_profile');
            }
  public function do_upload($resume){

    if($this->upload->do_upload($resume))
    {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data($resume));

    $this->load->view('user_profile',$data);
    }
    else
    {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors($resume));
    $this->load->view('user_profile', $error);
    }
    }
```

currently always error.... Error! Please try again later . so appreciate some pointers here to upload both file and form data together and save file location in database without ajax/jquery.

Thanks

Comment: You don't ever _need_ JavaScript, jQuery or anything else  to use the Codeigniter upload library, as long as your web server, upload directory and PHP code are all well written. I know, I do uploads the old fashioned way :) What you must do, and is probably the reason why you're getting errors is set your form as `multipart/form-data` and handle both parts separately on your backend (with `$this->upload` for the file and `$this->input->post()` for the form fields)

Comment: this is problematic logic. your main issue is missing multipart as javier and the answer suggested, but doing `if($this->upload(...` is weird. just make it all one controller function. further you are confusing `form_error()` and `validation_errors()` with `display_errors()` the first two are methods are from the form validation library and aren't part of the `upload` library and thus won't work as you expect them to work.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet i think i am missing that link of passing file data and catching properly in controller,upload ,on success grab url and store to database. at present, using $this->input-post($filenametag) in controller which giving me error..`You did not select file to upload`but on application profiling i see the posted file data. some example code is much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: @Alex Thanks, got your point on errors, now catching them in two different views(user_profile.php and displayerrors.php) to watch those errors.

Comment: fyi `do_upload` automatically looks for an upload field with the name `userfile`, yours is `resume` do it should be `do_upload('resume')` passing a $_post field has nothing to do with the $_files array (where files reside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !
4 important steps needed and some missing in most Q&A in all other posts to make this complete.will share samplecode in github when i get sometime.

1. form encryption type must be enctype="multipart/form-data" (thanks 
   to @Javier Larroulet and @dexter )
2. do_upload method by default look for file field with name=userfile
   (Thanks to @Alex ! for referencing this), so, if you have your
   form's file field name different than *userfile*, **then only it is
   required to mention as do_upload('filefieldname') otherwise
   optional**
3. loading of upload library configuration is tricky..  **if you
   autoupload the upload library , then load->library upload config will fail!**, you
   just =>*initialize* it.$this->upload->initialize($config); if you
   are not using  autoload for upload library, then yes, you can load it
   from controller.  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
4. when ever, you are using upload, you have to catch the form validation errors
   and data errors separately (again thanks to @Alex for pointing this)

a nice documentation is given from codeigniter at this link (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller ) but doesn't highlight routine mistakes.

hope this post help someone not to waste another 24 hours to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Change the form definition to the following:

```
<form class="row" action = "<?php echo base_url('user/user_profile'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="updateprofile" >
```

Comment: Thanks dexter! thats changed,but this one is  not the final.  i am getting error as "You did not select a file to upload." but when did application profiling ..i see file is posting to controller...as `$_POST['updateprofile']   updateprofile
$_FILES['resume']   
Array
(
    [name] => 28112017_NNNN.pdf
    [type] => application/pdf
    [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php5777.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 821163
)` basically am looking for one example code where we upload some file and data then catch the filepath on server and store database table.